# dynamically set the props of React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've an object of props values where the key is the name of the component and the value is the prop's value

```
{
    "ComponentA.prop1": 23,
    "ComponentA.prop2": 100,
    "ComponentB.prop3": 200,
}
```

then I've all these components inside a form

```
<form>
   <ComponentA />
   <ComponentB />
</form>
```

How can I dynamically pass all the defined props to the correct components elegantly.

Comment: Are you able to change the way the props are defined and the components are rendered? I just say this because there isn't really an "elegant" way to match string values to the names of imports. That is, you shouldn't go from the string "ComponentA" to a component which was imported under the name `ComponentA`. The best way would be to store the component in the object, so the object has the component to render *and* its props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if it works with your use case

```
const obj = {
  "ComponentA.prop1": 23,
  "ComponentA.prop2": 100,
  "ComponentB.prop3": 200
};

const getProps = (name) => {
  let nObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter((key) => key.split(".").shift() === name)
    .forEach((key) => {
      let nKey = key.split(".").pop();
      nObj[nKey] = obj[key];
    });

  return nObj;
};

<form>
   <ComponentA {...getProps('ComponentA')} />
   <ComponentB {...getProps('ComponentB')} />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the structure of your data?

```js
const data = [
  {
    component: ComponentA,
    props: {
      ...componentAprops,
    },
  },
  {
    component: ComponentB,
    props: {
      ...componentBprops,
    },
  },
  {
    component: ComponentC,
    props: {
      ...componentCprops,
    },
  },
];
```

Then you can simply map these into ui components

```
const elements = data.map(d => {
  const Component = d.component;
  return <Component {...d.props} />;
});
```